# Why doesn't this page render correctly in Internet Explorer?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, rendering

Have a look at this page:
http://labs.pieterdedecker.be/hetoog/layout.htm

It looks alright in Firefox, but IE messes it up. How come?

Comment: can you please say exactly what the problem is? i am using IE8 and it seems fine. is it that it does not fit within the browser window?

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of how it's supposed to look like? Seems fine here (tested on Chrome 4, Opera 10 and IE 8)

Comment: IE seems to take the whole width available - is that the issue?

Comment: @Amarghosh: yup, that's the issue. In Firefox, there is plenty of whitespace to the left and right of the main content.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your layout is a bit interesting. Instead of using empty table cells on either side of the page, you could take those out and achieve the centering using

```
body {
    width: 750px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

And you HTML could be something like this:

```
<body>    
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td class="splash_desc">...</td>
            <td class="splash_photo">...</td>
        </tr>
        ...
```

With this method IE will not take up any more space than other browsers and will fit nicely inside the 750px wide container.

**EDIT:**

To get the header bar stretch horizontally 100%, you must make another div for the content. So, instead of using the body element to set the width, use something like this:

```
<body>
    <table id="header"><tr>...</tr></table>
    <div id="wrapper">    
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td class="splash_desc">...</td>
                <td class="splash_photo">...</td>
            </tr>
            ...
```

And in CSS:

```
#wrapper {
    width: 750px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

This way you can have the table above wrapper to be 100% wide (just style it so), and the wrapper itself is 750px wide.

Comment: That works, but it ruins the soon-to-be navigation bar (on top of the page). How can I make sure it's stretched out 100% horizontally?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is

In IE6.0 `<td>&nbsp;</td>` wont support.

Specify width for the `<td width="20%">&nbsp;</td>`

and PNG Images not support in IE6.

Download from http://www.twinhelix.com/css/iepngfix/

file : iepngfix.zip (40kb) will solve the problem